# Solver and "Show Trial Solution" window

Tags: excel, loops, solver, vba

I am running the below Solver macro:

```
Sub Merton()
'
' Merton Macro

Dim i As Long
For i = 7 To 56
  SolverReset

  SolverOk SetCell:="$K$7", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$I$7:$J$7", _
Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

  SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$" & i, Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$H$" & i
  SolverAdd CellRef:="$K$" & i, Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$B$" & i

  SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

  SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

Next i

End Sub
```

and I keep getting the "Show Trial Solution" pop up because Solver pauses. I have then to press the "Continue" button to let Solver proceed. Is there any way to insert in the macro a command that tells Solver not to show the "Show Trial Solution" window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have the option `Show Iteration Results` selected. It might be enough to manually deselect it before running your code. Alternatively, at the top of your code put the line

```
SolverOptions StepThru:=False
```

and it should deselect that option.

If this doesn't fix the problem then the documentation at [solver.com](http://www.solver.com/excel-solver-show-solver-trial-solutions) says:

> The Show Trial Solution dialog box also appears (only once, not on each
>   Trial Solution) if you press ESC, or if Solver reaches one of
>   the Solving Limits (Max Time, Iterations, Max Subproblems or Max
>   Feasible Solutions) while solving a problem

perhaps you are exceeding limits and need to increase the limits that you are running into.

.

Comment: I increased the limits and added the line and the pop up stopped coming out